# Foreach dentro de foreach está duplicando valores PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, foreach

Estou tendo um problema de `looping`, estou trabalhando com 3 tabelas do Banco, seria tabela `Anuncio`, `Opcoes_Anuncio`(*interliga*) e `Opcoes`, estou tentando trazer os dados de opções junto com as opções selecionadas, mas acontece que está dando vários `looping`.

MYSQL

a minha query está assim

> `SELECT * FROM` `opcoes` `op` `INNER JOIN` `opcoes_anuncio` `oa` `ON`
>   `oa`.`opcoes_id_opcao` = `op`.`id_opcao` `INNER JOIN` `anuncio` `an` `ON`
>   `oa`.`anuncio_id_anuncio` = `an`.`id_anuncio` `WHERE`
>   `an`.`anuncio_id_anuncio` `= '17'` `ORDER BY` `op`.`id_opcao` `ASC`

PHP

```
<?php foreach ($opcoes as $val): ?>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="opcoes_id_opcao[]"
              value="<?= $row->id_opcao; ?>"
              id="<?= $row->slug_opcao; ?>" 
            <?php if($row->id_opcao == $val->opcoes_id_opcao) { echo "checked"; }?> >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="<?= $row->slug_opcao; ?>">
           <?= $row->titulo_opcao; ?>
        </label>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> [image: IMAGEM DO ERRO DE LOOPING]

Comment: Qual é a sua ideia nesse loop?

Comment: Tem que descrever bem mais para conseguir obter uma resposta satisfatória. o que tem `$show_opcoes` ? e o que tem `$opcoes` ? qual o resultado em html que esses dois for's dão e qual é que seria o correto ?

Comment: Pronto, tinha esquecido de subir a imagem, com ela fica muito mais fácil de visualizar o erro que acontece

Comment: No seu SQL tem um erro, aqui devia ser `WHERE an.id_anuncio`, mas fora isso a consulta não retorna registros duplicados, a menos que realmente foram gravados a mesma opção pro anúncio mais de uma vez. Poste o código dos seus 2 `foreach`, o problema deve estar aí.

Comment: Eu acho que seja erro no Foreach mesmo, mas eu to tentando trazer os valores normais que seria OPCOES e também trazer os valores marcados escolhidos antes que é OPCOES_ANUNCIOS, quando eu faço certo, ele só me retorna os 3 marcados, mas preciso dos valores OPCOES para que a pessoa seleciona outra opção

Answer (score 1):

Olá, difícil saber por que isso ocorre sem ver a estrutura das tabelas, mas um `group by opcoes_anuncio.anuncio_id_anuncio` pode resolver o problema.

Além disso, parece que seu código não está certo, tem 2 `endforeach`, e vc faz a iteração com a variável `$val`, mas abaixo usa `$row`. Parece que o código está errado ou incompleto.

Comment: Eu acho que seja erro no Foreach mesmo, mas eu to tentando trazer os valores normais que seria OPCOES e também trazer os valores marcados escolhidos antes que é OPCOES_ANUNCIOS, quando eu faço certo, ele só me retorna os 3 marcados, mas preciso dos valores OPCOES para que a pessoa seleciona outra opção

Comment: Nesse caso, usa o LEFT JOIN não resolveria? Se puder colocar a estrutura das tabelas facilitaria.